# USB Port not working for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: usb

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my system. But the usb port does not seem to be working. When I type `lsusb` in terminal, following is displayed on the screen:

```
Bus 002 Device 114: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:0062 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub.
```

However the disk utility shows *no media*. Kindly help me on this. Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you have connected a USB keyboard. Does it work? If it does, does it work on other USB ports? And what is the output of `ls /dev | grep [s,h]d` when a USB flash drive is connected? (This command should list all connected storage devices)

Comment: Run the following commands after connecting your USB device and look if the USB device get recognized or not? 1) lspci 2) lsusb 3) dmesg|tail

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/525095/175272

It may help you.