# USB devices don't work after installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, keyboard, system-installation, mouse, input-devices

I've installed Lubuntu 14.04 with USB mouse/keyboard and USB key with no problem.
After installation, I had no mouse, no keyboard, no access to USB key and no network.

I plug a PS2 keyboard for the first diagnostic and `lsusb` shows that devices are detected but they don't run.

Did you have idea to help me?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue (Network and USB failure with trusty) - but I'm not sure which of the following fixed it:

This is the last few lines of my root console history:

```
 1989  apt-get install linux-image-generic
 1992  depmod -a
 1993  update-initramfs -k all -c
 1994  apt-get install linux-firmware
 1995  apt-get update
 1996  apt-get upgrade
 1997  apt-get install linux-firmware
 1998  apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
 1999  update-initramfs -k all -c
 2000  reboot
```

I'm guessing it'll be #1998 (firmware for network card) and #1989 (Installs the linux-image-extra-generic package; USB support) and #1999 (Rebuild the initramfs files; insert new modules/firmware into initrd)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've used steps #1998 and #1999 as #1989 was already installed and that fixed my USB and networking issues.

Answer (score 0):

Install the input drivers meta package `xserver-xorg-input-all`

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make USB devices and networking (LAN) working by installing `linux-image-generic`:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic`

You might also need the non-free firmware modules:

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`