# Two USB ports stopped working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, xubuntu, serial-port

I have a HP pavillion g6, running Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I have 3 USB ports. For some reason, 2 of them stopped working this morning.

I have `xserver-xorg-input-all` installed, followed the [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482154/usb-devices-not-work-after-installation-of-ubuntu-14-04/525095#525095) which didn't work. My laptop is updated and upgraded to the latest version. `lsusb` outputs

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e3 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Valentine
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried on Manjaro live cd, and all ports are working. Isn't there an error log for usb ports so i can see whats going on?

My `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/skkmwc1xyfqwekm/AACHa0hUwWWWQWtjStndRGGCa?dl=0)

Comment: Boot from a live DVD/USB and test the 2 USB ports and edit your question ruling out hardware issues.

Comment: @user68186 I tried on Manjaro live cd, all ports are working

Comment: How about an Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB stick?!

Comment: @KarlRichter i don't have that right now, but why would i even need that? it's clearly a software issue and not a hardware issue

Comment: @Fischer That would should it's an Ubuntu issue. If it works in Manjora, but not in Ubuntu, it might give a clue.

Comment: @KarlRichter it's not an ubuntu issue, i have been using xubuntu 14.04 since beta days and only today the ports stopped working

Comment: @Fischer But it stopped working today on xubuntu? But not an xubuntu issue? Please explain?

Comment: @KarlRichter i mean if i use from live cd , it will work like it did before and i done it before, i update my system many times since i installed it and done many changes to it, but the ubuntu image will work like it once did - Lets assume that you are right and it was an ubuntu issue. does it change a thing? it doesn't, still a software issue that needs to be fixed,  my hardware is fine, ubuntu is an OS, an OS is nothing but bunch of software, therefore the method to fix this error is still the same practically

Comment: @Fischer: Does the update history report any kernel, driver or firmware updates just before the USB ports stopped working? To track config changes I use `etckeeper`, but that doesn't work retroactively.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it might, i dont remember, how to troubleshoot it if etckeeper won't detect it?

Comment: You can look up the package manager history in `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster here's my files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/skkmwc1xyfqwekm/AACHa0hUwWWWQWtjStndRGGCa?dl=0 anything wrong with them?

Comment: Please add the link to the question body for future reference. I see updates of the packages `linux-firmware-nonfree` and `linux-image-generic` on 17th and 19th of September – just before your problems arose. Can you try to boot the previous kernel <3.13.0.35.42 and see if the problem persists? If it doesn't, it'd be interesting to see the output of `lsusb` in working conditions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster okay, how to downgrade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17425/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-fischer).

Comment: @DavidFoerster im on android mobile app right now, can't go on chat but I read your message and tried to boot using Linux 3.11.x still won't work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here I got my USB3 ports not working after a while: only a restart fixes the problem.

After some research, I've found that a lot of USB3 ports presents a power management problem In a lot of different hardwares and OSs. You can find people reporting this kind of problem on Windows, Linux, etc.

So, I've disabled USB power management, and now everything is fine.

## 1. Disabling USB Power Management

For Ubuntu, `usbcore` module is compiled in the kernel, so we need to change the kernel boot parameters.

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to add the `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Note that `quit splash` were options already present. So keep other options you have too.

Save file and close.

## 2. Update grub

After save the file, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.

## 3. Check autosuspend after reboot

After reboot, check `autosuspend` value:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

And it should display `-1`.

Comment: I reinstalled so i cant test it, i opened a bounty for a week and no one answered so i decided to reinstall but thanks for the solution, if i it ever happen to me again, i know where to look

Comment: This does not work for me in 15.10.. autosuspend value remains `2`. Did something change in 15.10.?

Comment: @JonasAdler, in a quick look, in the latest kernel versions, the param to change is `autosuspend_delay_ms`, but I didn't try yet. Let me know if this works and I can update the answer.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha so "quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend_delay_ms=-1" ?

Comment: @JonasAdler Exactly!

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha thank! The setting is now in place, let's see if it works. I will report back.

Comment: @JonasAdler Any results?

Comment: Previous to using the fix I had days without problems. It works up until now! I hope it stays that way. I'll let you know

Comment: The solution answered by RaelGugelminCunha works for me too, but seems to have one disadvantage. After reboot and confirmation that autosuspend was switched from 2 to -1, command lsusb does not work any more.
After starting `lsusb` the shell hangs and Ctrl C does even not work. I have set autosuspend back to 2, `lsusb` works again and will try other solutions.

Comment: @Dr.Zuse This is odd. For me, `lsusb` continued to work. What frozen `lsusb` to me was the autosuspend trying to disable my USB device. Anyway, good you inserted this comment. Probably this can affect other users too. Thank you!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks! I was about to dismantle my laptop because I thought it was a hardware issue. Glad I don't have to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-usb-stops-working-problem-in-ubuntu.html lists another way to fix this

This method also edits the grub but instead of modifying `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` it modifies `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`.

Steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in terminal and press enter
3. Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
4. Modify the line to read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force irqpoll"`
5. After that, update the bootloader via terminal by typing `sudo update-grub` and pressing enter
6. Restart your system

This method is the same as given in the link above and it worked for me.

I use Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple solution you can try this:

first execute below command in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

after, reboot your computer and it's worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check if `External USB` is enabled in BIOS of yours computer. In my case, it somehow changed state.

This is purely dependent on your system, however this might solve the issue like it was for me.