# Ubuntu 14.04 Randomly Freezing

Tags: 14.04, hp, freeze

Just put ubuntu 14.04 on my HP 15.6" AMD A8 2.0GHZ quad-core laptop and am experiencing random freezes (need to do a hard shut-down/restart, no mouse or keyboard functionality during freezes). There seems to be nothing I can do to replicate the freezes and sometimes I can go hours without one, other times it will only take a few minutes after booting.

I have tried re-installing multiple times to no avail. Also tried switching my drivers but anytime I try to switch via the system preferences tab the computer automatically switches back to the recommended driver.

A few more details about the computer:3.3 GiB of memory, AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics x4 processor. For graphics running Gallium 0.4 on AMD Mullins.

Comment: Any USB3 port in your laptop?

Comment: Yes, two of them. Along with 1 USB 2.0 port

Comment: So, can you try this solution I've created to fix/disable usb3 power management issues? http://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/2-usb-ports-stopped-working/534464#534464

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen when you are browsing in Firefox?

I have the same problem as well.  It only seems to occur when I am browsing in FireFox and do some rapid moving around of the pages.

Also, I installed fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and get a slightly different reaction.  Instead of staying frozen until I reboot the computer, if I wait ab out 5 minutes, it goes to the log-in screen.  Of course, I just remember that when it happens, before waiting, I give it a 3-key salute and leave it alone after that.

Maybe that's the escape, but not the solution.

I'm using Nvidia graphics, so I guess you just ruled out the graphics driver being the culprit.

Comment: I noticed it happening with FireFox and with 'rapid moving around of the pages' but have had it happened with no browser open and with Chrome being used as the browser instead of Firefox. Haven't been patient enough to wait the 5 minutes but next time that happens I'll let it sit for a while.

Comment: Had another freeze. Let it sit for a while and never went to log-in screen.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too I have the same cpu WTF? Nobody has an answer? I tried re installing 3 times same thing. At first I though it was firefox but then it froze when I was using Xbmc and then chrome it happens randomly. I also noticed that it gets hotter than windows 8 so I installed powertop it the temperature felt cooler but it still froze on me. I also left it for 6 minutes doing nothing but nothing happend the only thing that responded was my wifi being turned on and off but that's it couldn't open a terminal or nothing.

Comment: Hey I figured out the problem there could be 2 fixes.                                           1. Change you're Graphics card driver.                                                                                                                                             2. If you're using Ubuntu 14.04.2 reinstall to 14.04.1.