# Shutdown takes too long after USB ports stop working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, dell, shutdown

I have bought a new laptop Dell Inspiron 3000 series with pre-installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After a few months of usage, I noticed that USB ports stop working without no reason. Such behavior repeats in totally random fashion. Also, after it happens and I try to shut down the laptop or restart, it takes too long to shutdown (more than 1 hour). And I have to power it off, which is not good. After restart USB ports work just fine. But then this repeats again after a few hours of work or do not repeat.

So I searched for some solutions and I stumbled upon [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/2-usb-ports-stopped-working). I tried it just yesterday, and it made everything even worse. Now I stumble upon this problem after a few hours, and USB ports stop working even after a restart. That`s why I changed my grub file back to the way it was.
I would be very grateful if you helped me to find the solution of this problem!

Comment: Which kernel version are you running? (`uname -r`)

Comment: @AndroidDev 3.13.0-124-generic