# Ubuntu 14.04 usb not working -> Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, grub2, usb

I acknowledge there are many questions about this problem but I could not find the right answer in my case.

I have tried to change grub options as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/2-usb-ports-stopped-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-usb-stops-working-problem-in-ubuntu.html) or even some combinations...

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried running command "rmmod usbhid && modprobe usbhid" ?

Comment: No. Just copy/paste the command ?

Comment: Yes. Try running command as sudo user.

Comment: Thank you very much, but what is it supposed to do ? It it a safe command ?

Comment: rmmod usbhid will remove usb driver and modprobe usbhid will install usb driver.

Comment: Is that command solves your issue?

Comment: No. I really do not know what is going on with these USB ports...