# Ubuntu 16.04 - 1 of 3 usb-c stopped working

Tags: 16.04, usb, xps, thunderbolt, usb-c

I am new to linux myself, and so far I have nothing but love for Ubuntu. So glad that I finally made the jump from Windows.

Anyway, yesterday I did a system update on laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.  Afterwards, 1 of 3 of the usb-c ports stopped working.

When I run `lsusb -t`, here is what I get

```
> /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
>     |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ax88179_178a, 5000M /:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub,
> Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub,
> Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub,
> Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
>     |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
>     |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
>     |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
>     |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
>     |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
>     |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

I have already tried the instructions in [2 usb ports stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/2-usb-ports-stopped-working) but their solution didn't work for me.

Not sure if it's hardware related or not, and I really don't want to reinstall to check.  Could someone please help and point me to the right direction?  The laptop is quite new, so I really hope it isn't a hardware issue.

Comment: To test that it's not a physical hardware problem you could test the ports when running a live USB of Ubuntu (16.04 or you could try 18.04 as well). Another option is to select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** from the grub menu, try an older kernel from the list and check whether the ports work again. I assume you're not dual-booting (or you could test the ports on another installed operating system), so pressing **Shift** on reboot will take you to the grub menu.

Comment: Thanks @pHeLiOn.  I end up calling Dell support and it turned out to be a hardware issue.