# Lenovo EasyCamera stops working after a while - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, webcam

I have a refurbished **Lenovo Ideapad 320** notebook, which i bought like 9 months ago. I started using its integrated camera (**Lenovo EasyCamera**) a few days ago, for videocalls anly. What i found strange is that, just after i boot up to **Ubuntu 18.04**, it works good and its sidelight is permanently turned on; but then, after being idle for a while or after keeping the camera on, it practically dies and stops working, all of a sudden. I don't know if it may be a driver, power, or any other kind of issue.

I have checked the output of `sudo lshw` on both times and, at the `usb` part (given the camera is internally connected via USB, as far as i know), it says this:

- Right after booting up, with camera working:

```
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth Radio
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: EasyCamera
                   vendor: SunplusIT Inc
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 53.17
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

- After camera has stopped working:

```
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth Radio
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

As well, i unsuccessfully tried:

- Unloading and reloading the `uvcvideo` kernel module on the run.
- Explicitly loading the `uvcvideo` kernel module at boot up, adding a line with its name at the `/etc/modules` file.
- Pressing both `Fn+Esc` and every hotkey my keyboard layout shows a sign of the screen or camera (`Fn+F6`, `Fn+F8` and `Fn+F10`).
- Using the Cheese and GTK UVC Video Viewer softwares to test the camera (none of them recognized it).

As an extra data, i got the logs of the `journalctl` result about this module, and found this:

```
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device EasyCamera (5986:210f)
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: uvcvideo 1-8:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: uvcvideo 1-8:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: uvcvideo 1-8:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: uvcvideo 1-8:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
mar 24 18:35:08 i320 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
mar 24 18:35:06 i320 systemd-modules-load[317]: Inserted module 'uvcvideo'
```

Should anyone know how to solve this, or have an idea that may help me find out what's going on, please let me know. I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It could be a power management issue,  could you give it a try for solutions on https://askubuntu.com/q/526082/26246 & https://askubuntu.com/q/185274/26246