# Caldigit Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Ports

Tags: 20.04, usb, thunderbolt, intel-nuc, peripherals

For some reason, the USB Ports on my Caldigit TS3+ Dock aren't getting recognized. The monitor connected to the dock is working fine; so it's only the USB ports that don't seem to be working.
They'll work fine if I unplug the dock from power before plugging it into the system, but then will stop working again the next time I need to power the computer off.

System Information:

| **PC:** | **OS:** | **BIOS:** | **Dock:** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NUCi5FNK | Ubuntu 20.04 LTS | FNCML357.0047.2020.1118.1629 | Caldigit TS3 Plus |

#### Terminal `boltctl` Results

```
 * CalDigit, Inc. TS3 Plus
   |- type:          peripheral
   |- name:          TS3 Plus
   |- vendor:        CalDigit, Inc.
   |- uuid:          0097d0f0-d971-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
   |- status:        authorized
   |  |- domain:     c5030000-0052-540e-03a8-d5828c549801
   |  `- authflags:  none
   |- authorized:    Thu 14 Jan 2021 01:47:21 AM UTC
   |- connected:     Thu 14 Jan 2021 01:47:21 AM UTC
   `- stored:        Tue 12 Jan 2021 10:26:39 PM UTC
      |- policy:     iommu
      `- key:        no
```

### What I've tried so far

- Disabled `OS ACPI C2 Report` in BIOS
- Updated `/etc/default/grub` to:
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0`

  - [Disabling USB Power Management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/two-usb-ports-stopped-working)
  - [Disable C-States](https://gist.github.com/wmealing/2dd2b543c4d3cff6cab7)

Comment: I am having the same issue on Fedora, did you find any solution. The dock is authorized, tho USB is not working

Comment: No, it actually just started working one day a couple months after I submitted the question. Still had some issues with the display not working after restarts, but at some point there must have been an update for Ubuntu or Mint that fixed it for me.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the Authorization in the UEFI to none

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I had this issue for a few days before realising I had to authorize the new Thunderbolt device (TS3) in the settings.

Comment: Yeah, I verified with `boltctl` it was automatically authorized. I tried authorizing it manually as well, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

While upgrading to point release shouldn't be done in anger, I'd recommend trying the latest Ubuntu Point release (perhaps on a live USB) and see if that works. Sometimes having a later kernel will include the necessary bits to make more hardware work.

The latest point release as of this post is 21.04, if that does work, you can weigh the options of upgrading to a point release, this will require upgrading every 6-9 months until you get to the next LTS at 22.04. These upgrades will change the kernel and system libraries so proprietary software may not work on the point releases.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem, when I plugged in the thunderbolt device to an already running environment. It worked w/o authorization when I restarted the system.
My system configuation was:

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path                 Device          Class          Description
===================================================================
                                         system         XPS 15 7590 (0905)
/0                                       bus            0VYV0G
/0/0                                     memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/37                                    memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/37/0                                  memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchro
/0/37/1                                  memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchro
/0/40                                    memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/41                                    memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/42                                    memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/43                                    processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-975
/0/100                                   bridge         8th Gen Core Processor H
/0/100/1                                 bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 
/0/100/1/0                               display        TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650
/0/100/2                                 display        UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile
/0/100/4                                 generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 
/0/100/8                                 generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-
/0/100/12                                generic        Cannon Lake PCH Thermal 
/0/100/14                                bus            Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 
/0/100/14/0              usb1            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/4                            communication  Bluetooth wireless inter
/0/100/14/0/7                            communication  Goodix Fingerprint Devic
/0/100/14/0/c                            multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/1              usb2            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                              memory         RAM memory
/0/100/15                                bus            Cannon Lake PCH Serial I
/0/100/15.1                              bus            Cannon Lake PCH Serial I
/0/100/16                                communication  Cannon Lake PCH HECI Con
/0/100/17                                storage        Cannon Lake Mobile PCH S
/0/100/1b                                bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Expr
/0/100/1b/0                              bridge         JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/0                            bridge         JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/0/0                          generic        JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NH
/0/100/1b/0/1                            bridge         JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/1/0                          bridge         JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0                        bridge         JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0/0                      bus            ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Co
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0/0/0    usb5            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0/0/0/1                  input          Microsoft
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0/0/0/2                  input          USB Receiver
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/0/0/1    usb6            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/1                        bridge         JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/1/0/1/0      ens1            network        I210 Gigabit Network Con
/0/100/1b/0/2                            bridge         JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Br
/0/100/1b/0/2/0                          bus            JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 US
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/0        usb3            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1b/0/2/0/1        usb4            bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c                                bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Expr
/0/100/1c/0              wlp59s0         network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1c.4                              bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Expr
/0/100/1c.4/0                            generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card
/0/100/1d                                bridge         Cannon Lake PCH PCI Expr
/0/100/1d/0                              storage        SSD Pro 7600p/760p/E 610
/0/100/1d/0/0            /dev/nvme0      storage        SSDPEMKF512G8 NVMe INTEL
/0/100/1d/0/0/1          /dev/nvme0n1    disk           512GB NVMe namespace
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/1        /dev/nvme0n1p1  volume         679MiB Windows FAT volum
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/2        /dev/nvme0n1p2  volume         127MiB reserved partitio
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/3        /dev/nvme0n1p3  volume         15EiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/4        /dev/nvme0n1p4  volume         989MiB Windows NTFS volu
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/5        /dev/nvme0n1p5  volume         14GiB Windows NTFS volum
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/6        /dev/nvme0n1p6  volume         1250MiB Windows NTFS vol
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/7        /dev/nvme0n1p7  volume         3815MiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/8        /dev/nvme0n1p8  volume         390GiB EFI partition
/0/100/1f                                bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3                              multimedia     Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
/0/100/1f.4                              bus            Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Co
/0/100/1f.5                              bus            Cannon Lake PCH SPI Cont
/0/1                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                                     system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/4                                     generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/5                                     input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/6                                     generic        PnP device DLL0905
/0/7                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/a                                     system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                                       power          DELL GPM0365
/2                       virbr0-nic      network        Ethernet interface
/3                       vnet0           network        Ethernet interface
```

With the Ubuntu version

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Based on the above problem w/o authorization, looking for USB devices was:

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then  trying a boltctl gave me:

```
● CalDigit, Inc. TB3-MiniDock-HM
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          TB3-MiniDock-HM
   ├─ vendor:        CalDigit, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          002531a1-95cb-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ status:        connected
   │  ├─ domain:     cb010000-0090-8f18-23aa-da2250318a24
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ connected:     Fri 15 Apr 2022 04:01:24 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        no
```

Note the "●" comes out as "yellow", of course assuming your using one of your default themes.
Then what fixed the problem was quite simply:

```
boltctl authorize <uuid>
```

thereby

```
boltctl authorize 002531a1-95cb-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
```

Subsequently when you run to verify

```
boltctl 
 ● CalDigit, Inc. TB3-MiniDock-HM
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          TB3-MiniDock-HM
   ├─ vendor:        CalDigit, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          002531a1-95cb-3d00-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     cb010000-0090-8f18-23aa-da2250318a24
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Fri 15 Apr 2022 04:10:52 PM UTC
   ├─ connected:     Fri 15 Apr 2022 04:01:24 PM UTC
   └─ stored:        no
```

Note: The "●" here come out as green in color here to indicate it is authorized.
To further validate it found all the devices

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C**
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It found the plugged in "Logitech and Microsoft" input devices in this case and additional 2x root hub ports

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C**
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```